# IsPublished method is throwing InvalidUriException when component is checked out

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am looping the components in a folder and searching a component whose one field of type DateTime lies in range current date to next 7 days on the basis of its published status.

But if any of the Components is checked out then IsPublished method throws an exception `InvalidUriException`. How can I handle this situation if I don't want to skip this checked out component by catching the exception and continue looping?

**Edit:**
The third line throws `InvalidUriException` for checked-out components.

```
componentUri = new TcmUri(node.Attributes[CommonConstants.Id].Value).GetVersionlessUri();
dummyComponent = engine.GetObject(componentUri) as Component;
bool isPublished = PublishEngine.IsPublished(dummyComponent , publicationTarget);
```

Comment: `IsPublished` of `PublishEngine` throws an exception? Please rephrase your requirement, I don't quite understand the case.

Comment: componentUri = new TcmUri(node.Attributes[CommonConstants.Id].Value).GetVersionlessUri();                                                       dummyComponent = engine.GetObject(componentUri) as Component;     bool isPublished = PublishEngine.IsPublished(matchComponent, publicationTarget);                                                     the third statement throws an exception when component is checked out.

Comment: The code example doesn't explain your problem. dummyComponent doesn't seem related to the rest of the code (and that's the wrong kind of cast). We can't see where matchComponent comes from. Are you sure this isn't just a logic problem in your code? Can you put in a breakpoint and get the value of the Uri which causes the problem, and then see whether the item exists?

Comment: Sorry I was willing to check the publishing status of dummyComponent. I want to push this dummy component in to my package so that I can read the fields of this component.

Answer (score 4):

Invalid uri exception means the tcm id (item) doesn't exist. When a component is checked out, it may have a minor version number appended to the uri, e.g. tcm:xx-yy-yy-v1.  So you need to grab that.

Try this: open the checked out component's version history and see what the latest version's ID is.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you pass in the component itself, shouldn't it be a TcmUri?
Even throws an exception when you hard-code the URI?

Answer (score 2):

Invalid uri exception is thrown if the method does not support version uri or editable uri. Use the versionless uri then it should work fine i think. U can use TcmUri.GetVersionLess uri method.

Comment: You have seen the code snippet I have attached.When I get tcm uri as versionless and used this statement                       dummyComponent = engine.GetObject(componentUri) as Component;             then it again appending v0 at the end of the component.

Comment: PublishEngine.IsPublished does not add v0. might be the engine.GetObject returning the checkout version of the item. Can you debug and see the TcmUri of the dummyComponent.